# Is the month pronounced Tishri or Tishrei?

Tags: tishrei

Is the month pronounced Tishri or Tishrei?  I have seen both.  Is one more authoritative than the other?

Comment: I'm curious, besides the emes, does it make any practical difference?

Comment: Is it seemly to mispronounce things when you are talking about holy matters?

Comment: I've only ever heard people say Tishrei.

Comment: @N.T. For example, in Ashkenazi slichot of Tzom Gedaliah there's a slichah that was apparently written by Rasag, where he writes: Do'achu k'hayom b'shlosha b'Tishri. On one hand, it's possible this was done only for the rhyming effect. On the other hand, not all rhymes in the various slichot actually rhyme.

Comment: “People tend to call Tishrei ‘Rosh Hashanah’ -Rashi, Rosh Hashanah 12b :)